# Check box / radio button in Linux (CentOS 7 - KDE 4) doesn't response

Tags: linux, centos, kde

It happens every time I open a Setting Dialog or something like that in my System or even in all applications (eclipse etc.)

When I click on the check box like this one, it just doesn't show up that it was checked, instead it stays empty like unchecked. Its functional effect does take response, but I mean here the optical effect. I don't know yet whether if a check box, radio button were clicked/checked or not.

It's so weird and I have just no word to describe it properly :(

Thank you very much.

Sample check box

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `System Settings` > `Application Appearance` > `GTK + Appearance` and select any widget style except "oxygen-gtk".

My graphics card is an Intel Graphics from an Intel i5 560UM processor.